# why the "1A" in where clause is identified as a column name?

Tags: mysql

why this sql can not execute?

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_190530 WHERE ID=1A;
```

I know 1A needs to be enclosed in quotes as it is a string,like "WHERE ID='1A';"
But i want to know the reason. why **1A** without the quotes is identified as column name in the sql?

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST_190530
(ID VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO TEST_190530 VALUES('1A');
INSERT INTO TEST_190530 VALUES('1');
INSERT INTO TEST_190530 VALUES('2C');

mysql> SELECT * FROM TEST_190530 WHERE ID=1;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 1A |
| 1  |
+----+
2 rows in set

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1A' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2C' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
2 rows in set

mysql> SELECT * FROM TEST_190530 WHERE ID=1A;
1054 - Unknown column '1A' in 'where clause'
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                               |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------+
| Error | 1054 | Unknown column '1A' in 'where clause' |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: Because that’s how the language is defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown column '1A' in 'where clause'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371397/unknown-column-1a-in-where-clause)